# iAd Banner is not showing in the approved iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

as I got my app approved I recognized that the iAd Banners don't show up unfortunately.
I decided to contact the iAd Support and their answer is:

> ...After investigating this issue we found your app is not sending ad requests to the iAd App Network.  We need to see ad requests so that the iAd App Network can attempt to fill them with an ad.
>   Please review and confirm you have the proper iAd code implementation in place as found in the useful resources below....

I answered that the banners show up in the actual app when I run and build it from Xcode.

Here's the code I use. I followed different tutorials so I can't understand why there should be a problem with the code.

I call createiAdBanner in viewDidLoad in the view I want the ad to be displayed.

```
    #pragma mark - iAd Banner

- (void)createiAdBanner {

    // iAd Banners
    if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
        adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    } else {
        adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    }
    [adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

    [adView setFrame:CGRectOffset([adView frame], 0, -50)];
    [adView setDelegate:self];

    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}

//
- (void)fixAdView {

    if (adView == nil) {
        return;
    }

    // Je nachdem, ob gerade ein Banenr angeigt wird
    if (adBannerViewIsVisible) {

        NSLog(@"ease in");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            // Endpunkt
            adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
            [tvInfoView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 110, tvInfoView.frame.size.width, tvInfoView.frame.size.height)];

        }];

    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"ease out");

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            // Endpunkt
            adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-adView.frame.size.height, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
            [tvInfoView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, tvInfoView.frame.size.width, tvInfoView.frame.size.height)];

        }];

    }

}

#pragma mark  ADBannerViewDelegate

// Banner wird vom Netzwerk zur Verfügung gestellt
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"load banner");

    if (!adBannerViewIsVisible) {
        adBannerViewIsVisible = YES;
        [self fixAdView];
    }


}

// Banner wurde entfernt
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"dismiss banner");

    if (adBannerViewIsVisible)
    {
        NSLog(@"dismiss banner 222");

        adBannerViewIsVisible = NO;
        [self fixAdView];
    }

}

    - (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {

        // Ad Banner Zustand aktualiseren, falls die Action vielleicht gerade ausgefüht wurde
        [self fixAdView];
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Was this issue resolved?  And what was the underlying problem?  I am waiting for my app. to be deemed appropriate by the iAd review.

Answer (score 17):

If you look in the iAd workbench (click the iAd icon in iTunes Connect), you can see the stats for your app, including "Requests." If this is zero, then your app is (*presumably*) not asking Apple for ads -- irrespective of the fill rate.

I just ran into the same situation where banners would appear fine in my developer version, but after submitting, nothing was appearing the iTunes version. When I logged into iTunes Connect, it said I had zero requests, and I was listed as "Live Ads," so I assumed the problem was with my app. I emailed Apple, and they were less than helpful.

... But, lo and behold, 4 days after my app was submitted, ads just magically started appearing. They've gotta have some internal process where even after your app is submitted, it needs to be cleared by some iAd person. It would be nice if they listed the status as "Pending Review" instead of "Live Ads" so that people won't freak out like I did.

Comment: I try to *click the iAd icon in iTunes Connect* and then **Sign In** but it does let me go though, even if I set the correct credentials, do you know why? I get no feedback at all, if credentials wrong, I get red alert

Comment: Yep, just happened to me, too - iAd only started showing up almost 24h after the app was approved. Was showing "Live Ads" all the time, but with 0 requests.

Comment: iad.itunesconnect.com leads to a domain on sale: iad.itunesconnect.apple.com to an unexisting page.

Comment: there is no such domain as itunesconnect.com. The real address is itunesconnect.apple.com, so apple.com is the domain name.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after updating my app to start using iAd (first week of january). On day one 6 requests then 3 days of 0 requests. I mailed support and they gave me the same reply that the app is not sending requests. But miraculously on the same day everything was ok and I am now receiving a few thousand requests per day, without changing anything.

So I guess there was some problem at their side….

Comment: @Kuatan And how did you contact them? Is there some form on iTunes connect or something?

Answer (score 4):

Just check "Messages" on iAd Network site. Apple sends an automatic message after your app is approved. The message says:

> When you submit your app, ##YOUR APP NAME##, for approval, it will also be reviewed by iAd for use on the App Network to determine its appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd advertisers. Once your app is approved, you will be ready to start earning revenue for ads that run in your app.

Answer (score 1):

When I use iAd in my apps, I use this great library called JTCAdBaseViewController(Github: https://github.com/tomohisa/JTCAdBaseViewController). This library implements iAd properly and uses a simple view controller and has lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Apple have changed the way , they approve things.
In my case they approved the App first and App, became live on store, but there were no iAD displaying at all.

After I have reviewed the ituens connect, iAD section, I figured out they now have different review separately if they will be making your App display iAd or Not.

Really very very stupid.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 9.3, Xcode 7.3, ARC enabled**

***iAd App Network will be discontinued June 30th, 2016.  Apps that were submitted after January 15th, 2016 will not receive ads.***

Please see: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a.

**For apps. submitted before January 15th, 2016 deadline:**

***Short answer: You must first wait for iAd review team to approve ad placement in your app.***

This is straight from iTunes Connect, Resource and Help [FAQ](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/67.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.7.1):

Note:  The most important part is in bold.

> How do I start generating revenue with the iAd App Network?
>
> To join the iAd App Network, you must:
>
> - Be a member of iOS Developer Program
> - Agree to the iAd App Network Contract, found in Agreements, Tax, and    Banking
> - Complete the required tax forms in Agreements, Tax, and Banking
> - Set up your banking information in Agreements, Tax, and Banking
> - Integrate the iAd Framework into your app and submit it for review
>
> **After your app has been approved and is in the Ready for Sale state, it also will be reviewed by iAd to determine the app’s appropriateness
>   for receiving ads from iAd advertisers. After your app has been
>   approved by iAd, you can start earning revenue for ads that run in
>   your app.**
>
> To see the ad performance of your app and the revenue generated by
>   iAd, go to the iAd section. On the iAd page that opens, in the
>   Monetize section, click View Your iAd Reports.

I agree that "Live: This app is receiving live ads." is a bit misleading.

Answer (score -2):

This depends on the review rate of the application, more your app is downloaded or reviewed, their becomes more chances to get adds on it.

Comment: Christians app is not sending requests, so thats where the problem is. Reviews or downloads have nothing to do with requests but could only impact the "fill rate".

Comment: actully it depends on apple how frequent they provides adds on your app seeing app's content, review, downloads etc.

Comment: Ashu, I don't want to go in a further discussion, but request should always be send. Then it's up to iAd what they want to do with it. Please check the meaning of request before you comment on this.